# Cambiar de Adapter (List a Grid) durante la ejecucion en un RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, recyclerview

Actualmente tengo una pantalla donde me muestra una lista de objetos, para ello he creado un `ListAdapter` que añadiré a mi `RecyclerView`. 
Me gustaría que al pulsar un botón la vista se me cambie a modo rejilla, utilizando un `GridAdapter`. Hasta ahora trato de cambiar el `Adapter` de mi recyclerView, pero me dice `No adapter attached; skipping layout`. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

```
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.ViewHolder> {
List<Product> items;
Context context;
public ListAdapter(List<Product> items, Context context){
    this.items= items;
    this.context=context;
}
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.cardproductlist, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Image image = items.get(position).getImage();
    holder.productName.setText(items.get(position).getName());
    String url = "La url que sea"
    Glide.with(context).load(url).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).into(holder.productImage);
    holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //TODO llamar a la ventana de ver el producto
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ClothsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("propia", true);
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}

static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView productName;
    ImageView productImage;
    CardView cardView;
    RecyclerView    recyclerView;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        productName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.productname);
        productImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.productimage);
        // recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        cardView = (CardView)v.findViewById(R.id.productcard);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class GridAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GridAdapter.ViewHolder> {
List<Product> items;
Context context;

public GridAdapter(List<Product> items, Context context){
    this.items= items;
    this.context=context;
}
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.cardproduct, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Log.d("AQUI;","ESTAMOS");
   // holder.productImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.planetas2);
    String url = "La url que sea";
    Glide.with(context)
            .load(url).asBitmap()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.avatar)
            .into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(holder.productImage) {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(Bitmap drawable, GlideAnimation anim) {
                    super.onResourceReady(drawable, anim);
                }
            });
    holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //TODO llamar a la ventana de ver el producto
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ClothsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("propia", true);
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}

static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView productName;
    ImageView productImage;
    CardView cardView;
    RecyclerView    recyclerView;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        productImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.productimage);
        cardView = (CardView)v.findViewById(R.id.productcard);
    }
}
```

Y para cambiar de Adapter hago lo siguiente dentro de un fragment:

```
  @Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle state)  {
    super.onActivityCreated(state);
    Log.d("CREANDO","onActivityCreated");
    listButton = (ImageButton)getView().findViewById(R.id.listOption);
    gridButton = (ImageButton)getView().findViewById(R.id.gridOption);
    gridButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    listButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           activateList();
        }
    });

    gridButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          activateGrid();
        }
    });
}

public void activateList(){
    Log.d("FRAGMENT GALLERY: ", "Activamos lista, numero de elementos: "+products.size());
    listButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    gridButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 1));
    ListAdapter listAdapter = new ListAdapter(products,getActivity());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

public void activateGrid(){
    Log.d("FRAGMENT GALLERY: ", "Activamos grid, numero de elementos: "+products.size());

    listButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    gridButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3));
    GridAdapter gridAdapter = new GridAdapter(products,getActivity());

    recyclerView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
    gridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: Lo mas óptimo es que un solo adaptador maneje toda la lógica, te dejo este ejemplo como referencia http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28581712/android-recyclerview-change-layout-file-list-to-grid-onoptionitemselected

Comment: @Bourne muchas gracias por tu respuest. Ese ejemplo ya lo habia visto, mi problema es que la lista y el grid no muestran los mismos datos, tengo dos cardview diferentes.

Answer (score 1):

Basándome del [enlace de SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28581712/android-recyclerview-change-layout-file-list-to-grid-onoptionitemselected) que ha comentado @Bourne

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Crear un variable `switchViewList` para usarla bandera/flag determinará si se debe mostrar la vista del `RecyclerView` en forma de Lista/List o Rejilla/Grid

```
private boolean switchViewList = true;
```

y el reciclerview

```
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
```

Crear un método para inicializar el recyclerview:

```
private void prepareRecyclerView() {
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(switchViewList ? new LinearLayoutManager(this) : new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
    ((SimpleItemAnimator) mRecyclerView.getItemAnimator()).setSupportsChangeAnimations(true);
    mAdapter = new CarAdapterChangeLayout(carsList,switchViewList,this);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

en el `SetLayoutManager` es donde se analiza la variable `switchViewList` si es verdaderos se le asigna el `LinearLayoutManager` y falso un `GridLayoutManager`

en el `onCreate` de la actividad

```
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
prepareRecyclerView();
```

El selector para cambiar de List a Grid

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        case R.id.action_switch_view:
            switchViewList = !switchViewList;
            prepareRecyclerView();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

En el adaptador del recyclerview en `onCreateViewHolder` es donde puedes inflar con una platilla para las listas y otra para la rejilla.

```
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(switchList ? R.layout.draw_item_list: R.layout.draw_item_grid, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}
```